# How to clone whole instance ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Can I copy/clone the whole instance from one to different?
How can I do that? Is there any widget?

If anyone can help me, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, with a few caveats:

- Only users with an Admin role can request a clone
- by default the clone target instance must be non-prod (this can be changed in the system properties though)
- personal developer instances cannot be a target instance

Instructions:

1. As an Admin (user with admin role), in the navigation menu of the
   source instance, go to "clone targets" and click "new".  It will ask
   for the target URl, user name  and password.
2. Now you have a clone target, in the navigation menu of the source
   instance, go to "request clone". You need to select the newly
   created target instance, a scheduled time for the clone (usually has
   to be a few hours in the future), and fillout your email address so
   you get updates on progress.

Once the clone is completed, you can log into the target instance which will be freshly cloned.

Comment: got an error

Cloning of Production instance to development instances is not supported. You cannot select dev60819 as a clone source or target instance. Please refer to KB0540342 for further details.

Comment: Please note the answer includes "personal developer instances cannot be a target instance".